how to save database connection code outside of the main window form to be called when needed within various forms
I am trying to find an example of a project or code that shows how to create separate methods to connect to the database, retrieve data, save data, and alter data with those methods saved in their separate class to be called when needed.
I can make it work when the code is included in the MainForm but i will have other forms needing to do many of the same things and didn't want to have to write it out on each form.
Main Form
-ask for information from the database
-calls DataBaseConnection method
-using user input to select what data is needed
-displaying data on MainForm
Class DataBase
-method DataBaseConnection
-method RetrieveData
-method SendData

Create a strongly typed dataset, and tableadapters for your data access.. I often feel with winforms there isn't much point using anything more modern because so much good, clever functionality (binding) is rigged up to work well with old devices like datatables

Try using interface and its implementation and inject it to any forms when necessary.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
